# How do I replace an infopath form with a new format of form which is up to date?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, infopath, automation

Working on a purchase order site which consists of a data entry form, which was created in infopath. Now I have to edit and replace this form since the infopath form is not up to date and I'm looking to create a new form which looks new and is easy to use. Which tool should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Check out PowerApps. It's not the easiest tool to use, and it has a little bit of a learning curve, it doesn't replicate all of InfoPath functionality, but it's the recommended forms to for rebuilding infopath forms moving forward.

Comment: should i create a new form in powerapps and replace it with the existing infopath form?

Comment: The answer is complicated. Was the infopath form for a form library or a list? If it's for a list, you can create a powerapp for the same list and then just phase out the IP form. If its an infopath form library, you'll have to build a new list (or lists), plus the powerapp, and then decide how much effort you want to put in to migrate data, as there is no migration path of any kind.